# the database construction of like button (like Facebook like or Google +1)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-like

I want to know the database construction of like button like Facebook like or Google +1 and so on.

Like button is a common element for social website. User can like and unlike a message to show their support to the message.

The system have to detect user liked or unliked this message before, to show the unlike or like button to user to click.

But how this function work and what`s the database construction?

I figured out this method:

Every message/post has a **like** column to save the serialized user like data.

```
Post table
id           content                                like(serialized user_id)
1           hi world                 a:4:{i:0;i:234;i:1;i:32;i:2;i:423;i:3;i:4215;}
2      this is a good day            a:2:{i:0;i:2324;i:1;i:342;}
```

and unserialize and detect the user_id before outputting the post

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($sqlresult))
{
  $like_data_array = unserialize($row['like']);
  if( in_array( $user_id , $like_data_array ) )
  {
     echo 'you liked this post';
     echo '<button>unlike</button>';
  }
  else
  {
     echo '<button>like</button>';
  }
}
```

But i think this method is too slow for large number of like. Especially the post has over 100,000+ like.

Is there any more efficient design?

Comment: @atif089 yes, i found an efficient method to handle this problem.

Comment: @Angolao I don't think atif089 asked this question just to know more about you. Do you consider sharing your efficient solution, just like you demand other people to share their efficient solution?

Answer (score 4):

In normalized databases this thing is done using three tables: 
users - with columns: id, name, etc. 
posts - with columns: id, content, etc. 
likes - with columns: user_id, post_id (user_id is foreign key from users, post_id is foreign key from posts) 
So if you want to see if a user liked a certain post you execute something like the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post_id = 123456 AND user_id = 1000
```

Comment: This method will create more and more MySQL queries for outputting content. It seems more ineffective.

Comment: What you want to do is to create a many-to-many relationship between posts and users. What I described above is the standard way to create this kind of relationship in an SQL (relational) database. Of course, every time you want to check, for example, which are the users that liked a certain post you have to dynamically create a query based on the post_id, but this is not an issue. Also you may want to check the answer given by @Qualcuno which contains some of the reasons why your approach will not work correctly in the long run with MySQL.

Comment: Yes, but try to image the situation that in social community website it is very common that displaying over 20-30 posts on user home page. To display this page, do you means you have to create 20-30 MySQL queries to read the number of like for the post and check the user liked or unliked the post, and one MySQL query to read those 20-30 post from friends who user followed? Also, user home page is automatically updating new message or refreshing their page, so i will create more and more query to process this data. But in my way, i just created only one MySQL query.

Comment: You create a single query for the whole page. See my comment above!

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do that with MySQL (or any other relational database), I would surely do as Andrei suggested. That is the "right" way! And this is what we have relational databases for, actually.
If designed correctly, with caching (memcached et similia, but also MySQL's query cache), this is not really inefficient.

anlai, your proposal of adding a column with serialized data is "wrong" for various reasons:

1. This is not good in high-concurrent environments, as Facebook is. Since you're always updating a row, your flow is as follow: read the value from MySQL, change it in your application, update the value in MySQL. To prevent concurrency issues, you will have to do this in a single transaction, thus locking the row for a (relatively) long time. This is really bad if you have thousands of concurrent requests wanting to do the same thing.
2. "text" columns have a maximum length. Thus, there's a maximum number of "likes" that you can add. Also, by continously enlarging the field, you're introducing a lot of fragmentation in the database file. This is really inefficient!
3. Last but not least, this is not the correct way of using a RDMS (Relational Database Management System), as MySQL is, "philosophically" speaking.

Anyway, everybody here answered thinking to RDMBS... But what if Facebook wasn't using RDBMS? (And probably they are not!)
We're in 2011, we have "NoSQL" databases too :)

Take, for example, MongoDB. With its schema-less pages you could create a "posts" collection, for example:

```
posts.url = url of the like
posts.likes = array of users who liked (for example posts.like = [{name: "john Doe", uid: 12}, {name: "Mario", uid: 43}] ).
```

By doing it this way you don't have to query other tables.
Updates (inserting a new element in the posts.like array) are atomic operations, so you don't have to worry about concurrency issues. 
And this is what MongoDB (or other non-relational DBMS) is what is designed for.

Comment: OK, but in common situation, clicking the like is not a high require event. It is impressive that one post have over 1,000+ likes, and so just do SELECT -> unserialize -> array_push -> serialize -> UPDATE 1,000+ times. But user home page will load over 10,000+ pageviews (that`s not too much right?) in common situation. So you have to create 150,000+ queries to output the post and load the number of like and check the user liked or unliked this post. Is it better for high-concurrent environments?

Comment: If I were you, I'd REALLY consider the "NoSQL" way for this. Anyway, if you need MySQL... For example, you would first select all posts (SELECT * FROM user_wall WHERE user_id = ?), then select all the likes (SELECT count(like_id) FROM post_likes WHERE post_id IN ([list of post_ids]) GROUP BY post_id), and then get the user ids (SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN(...) ). It's just 3 queries! (I suggest you not to query for each post, but query for all posts at the same time).
The serialization thing is bad also because you have a limit on the number of likes!

Answer (score 0):

The essentials are there. I think this operation is only constrained by Database extraction so what you have to do is optimize your queries for getting only what's relevant for that user on that post and if you have too many computed fields you should consider a redundant table of computed operations.

I really don't think Facebook does an special optimization for 'Like' buttons different from having distributed caches for areas of users (f.e. having a prequeried set of data for users that have logged in). And Facebook has a truly huge userbase.

Comment: If Facebook using Memcached for caching the like data, i think that it is still a big project to find the liked user_id, searching a big Array including 100,000 user_id?

Comment: memcached stores everything in memory, and all keys are inserted into a hash table (binary tree). Thus, it is BLAZING fast. Searching an element in a list of 100,000 user ids takes really short time (complexity is O(log2(n)), so to search 1 in 100,00 you just need to do about 16 iterations!)